# Search engine bundle with dynamic DBAL connection

Tags: symfony, search-engine, dbal

I have a SF2 application using multiple database connections. There is a database for each user account, so their number isn't static.
I use a DBAL connection factory to access a database depending on which user is logged in.

I need to integrate a search engine bundle that can work well with this type on configuration.

It should be able to :

- generate search indexes per database
- manage indexes for databases that have identical structures (same table and column names)
- do search requests only in the database related to the logged user.

I know it's a custom configuration and not very popular but I hope somebody can help me find maybe the start of a solution, here. Thanks.

I have already checked Elastica and Solr bundles, but I don't know how to configure them without modifying the code.